# Help understanding load switch datasheet

Tags: switches, battery-charging

I am hoping to use this load switch:

[AP2171 Datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP2161_71.pdf)

I'll be using it to control battery charging in a portable device. I chose one with reverse current blocking to ensure there is no reverse leakage from the battery when the device is powered off. In that state, there will be battery voltage (1.2 V) to the OUT pin, but no voltage to the IN pin or EN pin.

I have two questions:

Will the reverse-current blocking be in effect when the device is powered off, i.e. when there's no voltage to the IN pin or EN pin?

Is it okay to have a voltage on the OUT pin when there is no voltage to the IN pin?

I'm confused because in the Absolute Maximum Ratings it says that the maximum voltage for OUT is Vin +0.3 V, which suggests to me that I shouldn't supply battery voltage to OUT when there's no voltage on IN. However, on page 4 they list the reverse leakage current (1 uA) when Vin is 0V and Vout is 5 V. That seems to suggest that it's fine to have 5V on OUT when there is no voltage on IN.

Comment: Did you read the data sheet? Search for words "not recommended", does that fit your scenario?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that note. It looks like the AP2171A may be suitable for this application: [link](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP2161A_71A.pdf). However, I still am not sure I understand why it says that Vout is limited to Vin +0.3V(?)